# How to "select all" in vim without losing cursor position?

Tags: vim

My mswin.vim contains the following command for Ctrl-A

```
inoremap <C-A> <C-O>gg<C-O>gH<C-O>G
```

This command correctly selects all lines in the file but also makes the cursor jump to the end of the file (undesired side effect). Is there a way to "select all" without moving the cursor?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that this cannot be achieved. Since in visual selection mode, the cursor will be either at the beginning or end of the visual range. Any motion in visual mode will lead to the visual selected range changes ( depends on the visual mode: char/line/block-wise).

The point is, what do you want to do after `select-all` and `kept the cursor position`?  It may be a X->Y problem, just tell us what is your final goal. There could be better solution for it.

Btw, `C-A` is so useful to increment numbers, maybe you want to reconsider the map trigger?

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to quickly auto-indent a file with Ctrl-A + =. I am sure there is a way to do it via a command but I will fail to memorize it (coming from windows world)

Comment: `gg=G` will auto format/indent your file if you set the filetype correctly. if you want to go back to your cursor position (approximately, because auto-indent could change your origin cursor line), you could before doing `=`, set a mark, and jump back after `=` @user3367166

Comment: An easier option to go to the previous cursor position: `''` (that's the single quote button pressed twice)

Comment: @Jan – `''` gets you back to that line but at the beginning of it (as if pressing `^`) rather than the exact position you had before. This not a problem using `getpos()` and `setpos()` such as in [g3cko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23439041/519360).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and fastest way is to use: <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> and then go over to Google Docs (or wherever) and paste.

Comment: Thanks, this command copies the content of file into the clipboard, however I want to *select* the content, not copy it.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at `getpos` `setpos` - maybe you can wrap what you want in something like this:

```
function! TestFunc()
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    normal ggVG
    " -- do something
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

In vim you can do this by going to the text you want to delete. Instead of typing I for insert type v starting from the text you want to delete. Next, you can arrow down to where you want to delete the text, then press v again. You now have selected the text range you want to get rid of. next press I and backspace.
source https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/oldhelp/vim/selection.html